# Limiting kafka ksqlDB query result for web usage

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, ksqldb

I need to limit the amount of lines returned in a ksql query.

At the moment this works well :

```
SELECT * FROM foo_view WHERE id = 123;
```

And I need something to help me page the results to my web page. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM foo_view WHERE id = 123 limit ROW 50;
```

Is it possible to do such thing? What are the alternatives for mentioned challenge?

Comment: I suppose you could compare how the Confluent Control Center limits its KSQL UI results